# QueryDSL Issue: Filtering Nested Collections in Spring Boot with One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl, criteria-api

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using QueryDSL for database queries. In my application, I have three classes: **ClientGroup**, **Client**, and **ClientBook**. The **ClientGroup** class has a one-to-many relationship with **Client**, and **Client** has a one-to-many relationship with **ClientBook**.

Here are the simplified class structures:

```
@Entity

@Getter

@Setter

@NoArgsConstructor

public class ClientGroup {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue

    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true)

    private String groupName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

    private ClientGroupType clientGroupType;

    private Boolean enabled = true;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ClientGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)

    private List<Client> groupClients = new ArrayList<>();

    @Version

    public Integer optLock;

}
```

```
@Entity

@Getter

@Setter

@NoArgsConstructor

public class Client {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue

    private Integer id;

    @Column

    private String clientName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)

    private List<ClientBook> clientBooks = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

    @JoinColumn(name = "client_group_id")

    private ClientGroup clientGroup;

    @ManyToOne

    private ClientCategory clientCategory;

    private LocalDate createdDate = LocalDate.now();

    @Version

    private Integer optLock;

    private Boolean enabled = true;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ClientBook {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String clientBookIdentifier;
    private String bookName;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BookType bookType;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Client client;
    @Version
    private Integer optLock = 0;
    private Boolean enabled = true;
}
```

I want to fetch **Clients** from the database, filtering them based on the *clientGroupType* of **ClientGroup**, and sort the results by *createdDate* and *isPremiumClient*.

Additionally, I need to exclude certain entries of **ClientBooks** based on *bookIdentifier* from the *clientBooks* in returned **Clients** List

While I can achieve this using SQL directly in the database, QueryDSL or CriteriaAPI doesn't seem to ignore **ClientBook**s with the specified *bookIdentifier* in *clientBooks* array within the **Client** class. It retrieves all the books instead.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can address this issue?

P.S. Please note that field names and class names have been simplified for clarity.

I tried variations of code below using Criteria API and QueryDSL. But every time got all of clientBooks or *InvalidPathException*

```
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Client> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Client.class);
        Root<Client> root = criteriaQuery.from(Client.class);
        Join<Client, ClientBook> clientBookJoin = root.join("clientBooks");

        Predicate groupTypePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("clientGroup").get("clientGroupType"), ClientGroupType.SOME_TYPE);
        Predicate bookIdentifierPredicate = criteriaBuilder.notEqual(clientBookJoin.get("clientBookIdentifier"), "some_identifier");

        criteriaQuery.select(root)
            .where(criteriaBuilder.and(groupTypePredicate, bookIdentifierPredicate))
            .distinct(true);

        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```